# JFrame cannot find 'pack' method

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

I'm taking a beginning Java class and an assignment requires that I write a class to represent a JPanel with buttons to increment and decrement a value and a label to display the value.  Then, I have to create a separate class which instantiates the panel and adds it to a frame.  I'm trying to have the frame resize to fit the size of the panel by running the pack method.  I try to call the frame's pack method by using:

```
SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(JFrame.class, this).pack()
```

I get a "cannot find symbol - method pack()" error.  The getAncestorOfClass is definitely returning a JFrame, and it is the correct JFrame.  When I run the pack method from inside the driver class where the JFrame is created, there are no problems.  Any ideas why it can't find the pack method?  Is it because I'm trying to run this from a separate class file?  I also can't access some other JFrame methods such as getContentPane, but I *am* able to access some others such as add.  Huh?

Comment: Why don't you just call `jframe.pack ();`?

Comment: Like I said, I'm doing this for a class, and this assignment requires that I create a separate class to represent the JPanel.  I can't simply reference the JFrame because it isn't defined in the class where I need to call the `pack` method.

Comment: And you're sure that you don't have to call `pack` on the JPanel? You wrote `Then, I have to create a separate class which instantiates the panel and adds it to a frame.` so I thought, you could call `pack` there.

Comment: JPanel doesn't have a `pack` method, and my panel class extends JPanel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method `SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass` returns a `Container`. Now, you know that `Container` is really gonna be a JFrame, but the compiler doesn't. And Java is a static language, not a dynamic one that'll just try to call the method regardless of whether the class declares it or not.

Since `Container` doesn't have pack method, the compiler's gonna complain. You'll need to cast to JFrame to make it work:

```
((JFrame)SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(JFrame.class, this)).pack();
```

Careful, though... The method can return null if no suitable ancestor was found. You might want to check that first.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know the compiler worked like that.  I'll add an exception handler to deal with the 'null' issue.

Comment: It's different from, say, Ruby. That language's interpreted, so there's no static checks up-front to let you know what you can and cannot call. If you happen to call a non-existing method, tough luck. Of course that does open up all sorts of possibilities regarding runtime extension and [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing). Since the Java compiler sees a return type Container and it doesn't have `pack`, it'll complain. Cast it to JFrame, however, and all is well. Unless you're trying to cast something that isn't JFrame, in which case you get an exception at runtime.

Comment: The only other language I've ever really used is Python -- I've been spoiled by its typing discipline :P

Answer (score 3):

You need to cast it to JFrame:

```
((JFrame) SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(JFrame.class, this)).pack();
```

Comment: Ah, getAncestorOfClass returns a generic Container, no matter what type I'm looking for, thank you!  I'm just starting here; I'll come back to vote up your answer when I have some reputation myself :)

Answer (score 1):

The [`SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(Class, Component)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#getAncestorOfClass%28java.lang.Class,%20java.awt.Component%29) method return a component, and not a JFrame.